# RC Children routes aren't resolving getting blank page

Tags: angular

In my app.module.ts I have:

```
import {settingsRouting} from './../../pages/settings/settings_routing';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomePage }
];
export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

And in my settings_routing.ts I have:

```
    const settingsRoutes: Routes = [
      {
        path: 'settings',
        component: SettingsPage,
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            children: [
              { path: 'account', component: AccountSettings },
              { path: 'profile', component: ProfileSettings }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ];

export const settingsRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(settingsRoutes);
```

I'm getting a blank page when trying **'/settings/account'** and **'/settings/profile'**, how can I fix this?

NB: I still want to show stuff from my master settingspage. I want it to have a  for it's children

Comment: Try rearranging your path something like this: `{ path: 'settings', children: [ { path: '', component: SettingsPage}, { path: 'account', component: AccountSettings }, { path: 'profile', component: ProfileSettings } ] }`

Comment: No luck, not working :(

Comment: anything in the console?

Comment: Nop. Actually I've moved the settings route config into the main app.module and now '/settings' is resolving' but not it's children...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, SystemJS started requesting files from '/profile/node_modules/' and it was failing silently.

Ensure you have 'baseURL: '/' in your systemJS config.